# How do you factor over a Z field?

Tags: matlab, math, mupad

I have to factorize a polynomial e.g.
[image]

over the field of Z5 using Matlab or Mupad.
And i tried everything read a lot of Matlab and Mupad documentation and still can't find it, so i am guessing it is the math i don't know that's going to help me factor it.

Comment: Matlab has a few functions which work with Galois fields but isn't really optimized for such things. In contrast, [PARI/GP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PARI/GP) is designed for number theoretic calculations and has a function called `factormod()` which factors polynomials over finite fields.

Comment: If you reduce all the coefficients modulo 5 (including the constant coefficient), you should be able to factorise quite easily by inspection. No need for a general factorization algorithm for this particular example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a mupad command to do what i needed.
[image: Mupad command to factorize over a field]

Still thanks for exaplaining the math behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't kill a mosquito with a cannon!

You only need to find a root between `0`, `1`, `2`, `-2`, `-1`.

Also, given that x<sup>5</sup> = x, the problem reduces to finding `x` such that

```
 2x + 2x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 - 3 = 0
```

and since `x ≠ 0`, `x^4 = 1` hence

```
 2x + x^3 + 2x^2 - 1 = 0
```

Well, let's try!

```
 1:  2 + 1 + 2 - 1 -> -1
 2: -1 + 3 - 2 - 1 -> -1
-2:  1 - 3 + 3 - 1 ->  0 -> root!
```

Then the polynomial is divisible by (**x** - 3), and you can repeat the procedure with the quotient until there are no roots left.

## Addendum

After dividing by (**x** - 3) we get

**x**<sup>4</sup> + **x**<sup>2</sup> + 1

which we can expressed as

(**x**<sup>2</sup> + 1)<sup>2</sup> - **x**<sup>2</sup>

or

((**x**<sup>2</sup> + 1) - **x**)((**x**<sup>2</sup> + 1) + **x**)

To find the factors of degree 2 programmatically, just try with **x**<sup>2</sup> + `a`**x** + `b` for `a` and `b` between `0` and `4`.